# Sign up Process - Usability

Tags: android, usability, registration

We are doing a Mobile App only sign up as we are not launching the web application immediately.

We need to capture as much information of the user to give them a personalized service

We had planned to capture the following data from them during Signup

1. First Name
2. LAst Name
3. Email Id
4. Password
5. Birthday day - Date Picker
6. Gender - Spinner
7. City - Spinner or get Location via GPS
8. Mobile Number
9. Profile Photo

For some reason i feel the signup rate will be affected. So can some one suggest how i can do the same and get the user to give the following data even may be just after signup

Comment: It is interesting, but I think this question belongs to http://ux.stackexchange.com/ where UX experts live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could let the user sign up with just e-mail and a password.

Then when the user starts using your services, you can put in hints and/or perks for the user to fill in the other information e.g.:

"If you fill in your personal data, you get the Super-Duper Cool Weapon of Ultimate Destruction for free."

Some websites provide a "Your profile is XX % finished" somewhere for the user to notice, which might also be possible to implement in a mobile app.

In the end - users hate long sign up rutines, but they will love to fill in information if there's a benefit to them in form of usage of the site/app, perks/rewards or improved services.

All in all: As long as you make sure you tell the user that filling in the info is to his/her advantage - I'm pretty sure people will do so.

---

You could also consider parring your service with Facebook/Twitter login - that way people won't have to fill in anything, except grant your app/service access on Facebook/Twitter.

Comment: we do have the Facebook Login this is for people who want to other wise do it :) thanks a lot i think i will stick to it name, email and password :)